# MYSQL Count on a Group By Table

Tags: mysql, sql

Okay So here are my three tables users, comments and posts.

users(**username**)  - Primary Key username

posts(*author*, **postId**) - Primary Key postId, Foreign Key author to users username

comments(*commentor*, *postId*, **commentId**) - Primary Key commentId, Foreign Keys commentor to users username and postId to posts

I'm trying to figure out how many comments each post. Then the sum of of comments on each posts that belong to the same user.

Basically I want to know how many comments each user has *received* not how many comments they have made.

Please I really don't know what to do!

Ideal Ouput

username  totalComments

- PaulBunyan     10
- User2                20
- etc..

Comment: Please show the code you attempted and found to not produce the correct results.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want:

```
select p.author, count(*)
from comments c join
     posts p
     on c.postid = p.postid
group b p.author;
```

Answer (score 0):

The best approach to building multiple joins and queries is always Divide and Conquer. In your case, I would start with building a query that will say the number of comments each post has, then join that result with the table that lists which authorID made each post and then join with the table that has the author names.